# Force a grid to be square in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to create a plot using pgfplots so that the grid lines are square,  while maintaining all the other labeling and such. I can manually set the height and width of the plot, but I'm not sure how to get the ratio right so that the grid ends up being a square. Below is a MWE where the axis is labelled like I want it, but the grid are rectangles as determined by pgfplots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle, xlabel = $t$, ylabel = {},
    xmin = -0, xmax = 8.5, ymin = -0, ymax = 4.5,
    ytick = {1,2,3,4}, %height = 40mm,
    xtick = {1,2,3,...,8}, %width = 80mm,
    grid = both
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `axis equal` isn't what you are searching for, then it is most likely `axis equal image`.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        xlabel = $t$,
        ylabel = {},
        xmin = -0,
        xmax = 8.5,
        ymin = -0,
        ymax = 4.5,
        ytick = {1,2,3,4},
        xtick = {1,2,3,...,8},
        grid = both,
        axis equal image,       % <-- added
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 3):

you need to add `axis equal,` to `axis` options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis equal,     % <---
    axis lines=middle, xlabel = $t$, ylabel = {},
    xmin = -0, xmax = 8.5, ymin = -0, ymax = 4.5,
    ytick = {1,...,4}, %height = 40mm,
    xtick = {1,...,8}, %width = 80mm,
    grid = both
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    x=1cm, y=1cm,     % <---
    axis lines=middle, xlabel = $t$, ylabel = {},
    xmin = -0, xmax = 8.5, ymin = -0, ymax = 4.5,
    ytick = {1,...,4},      %height = 40mm,
    xtick = {1,...,8}, %width = 80mm,
    grid = both
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: So that has made the grid into a square (huzzah!), but now the y-axis (and the grid lines) extend far beyond the range 0 to 4.5. I want to maintain that the bottom of the y axis is 0 but the top is 4.5. I think your fix has forced it to be as long as the x-axis.

Comment: @James, see added alternative solution, you maybe more liked it :-)